# Obtaining a datetime value when certain field conditions have been met

Tags: sql, datetime

We have a system that monitors field changes for a record in a table we'll call **history**. In this situation I'm focusing on the status of one field and the date value supplied from another field.

Every time a record is saved a new row is created with `hist_id` (PK) and `trans_dt` (SK) created against `record_id` (SK), along with a `field_id` that determines the field affected, `field_text` provides the value of the field if the field is a text field, whereas `field_dt` provides a datetime value if the field is a datetime field. Each save only records the deltas made, not the overall record as a whole.

As time progresses users may update records for a field we'll call "`status`" (field_id = 1) with one of two statuses **"A"** or **"B"**, or nothing at all. They may also update the field called "`status_dt`" (field_id = 2) with a certain datetime.

I'm trying to determine the first point where both the "`status`" field is defined with status **A** and the "`status_dt`" field is defined with a date... And spit out the value of `status_dt` at that point in time.

The only problem is, this can happen in one of three ways:

1. The "`status`" field is entered first, the record saved, and then the "`status_dt`" is entered and then the record saved.
2. The "`status_dt`" field is entered first, the record saved, and then the "`status`" is entered and then the record saved.
3. Both the "`status`" field and the "`status_dt`" are entered at the same time and then the record saved.

Moreover, there is the possibility of that the "`status`" field can be flipped back and forth between "A" and "B"; as well the value of "`status_dt`" could also be altered over and over.

So potentially we could get something like this:

```
hist_id trans_dt          record_id field_id field_text field_dt
------- ----------------- --------- -------- ---------- -----------------
      1 28/11/16 11:37:56         1        3 N/A
      2 09/12/16 11:52:51         1        4 Yes
      3 01/01/17 12:45:17         1        2            28/02/17 00:00:00
      4 14/07/17 09:01:58         1        1 B
      5 14/07/17 09:01:58         1        2            01/07/17 00:00:00
      6 14/07/17 09:01:58         1        5            31/07/17 00:00:00
      7 14/07/17 11:11:30         1        1 A
```

So in this instance the point in time where both the "`status`" field (`field_id=1`) is defined with status A and the "`status_dt`" field is defined with a date, is at `hist_id=7`, but we'd historically go back to the point where `hist_id = 5` to obtain the `status_dt` date (where `field_id = 2`), whereby as a result, both conditions are met by the time the status is redefined as **"A"**; and so the code should return `01/07/17 00:00:00`

Is there a way to query this date value at the first point where both fields (fields 1 and 2) have both been defined with field 1's status of "A", given the possible three ways these fields could be populated?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm currently using CCL (Cerner Command Language) which borrows off Oracle. Does that help?

Comment: from that sample data, what is the "expected result"?

Comment: `01/07/17 00:00:00`, in this case. This is the date required. So chronologically, although the Field 2 is set with the date, the status of Field 1 needs to be set to "A", which by then both fields have met their conditions.

So call it a historic look-back...

Comment: I still don't think the sample is viable. How does a value of "A" set at 11:11:30 get related to a date set at 09:01:58 and IF 09:01:58 is the exact same time for 2 different rows then there is no guarantee time alone will find the "first", `hist_id` could be used as a time-breaker if required. Have you tried the query already provided on real data?

Comment: @used_By_Already You're forgetting the `field_id`. I'm referring to the datetime set only when `field_id = 2`. The datetime of `31/07/17 00:00:00` is for when `field_id = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to determine the first point where both the "status" field
>   is defined with status A and the "status_dt" field is defined with a
>   date... And spit out the value of status_dt at that point in time

But the sample data you provided doesn't seem to support this scenario, row 6 is the only reference to status of "A" but there is no field_dt set at or after the time of row 6.

So, I have written the following query as if you were looking for the first occurrence of status = "B" instead. You can simply alter the relevant where clause condition to suit. Note I am using ROW_NUMBER() [because CCL documentation](https://wiki.ucern.com/display/public/1101discernHP/ROW_NUMBER+using+Discern+Explorer) indicates this is supported and this function, when combined with OVER() is helpful when looking for logic such as "first" or "earliest" (conversely also useful for "last" or "latest") by partitioning and ordering the data to suit.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE HISTORY
>     ("HIST_ID" int, "TRANS_DT" date, "RECORD_ID" int, "FIELD_ID" int, "FIELD_TEXT" varchar2(4), "FIELD_DT" date);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (1, to_date('28/11/16 11:37:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 3, 'N/A', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (2, to_date('09/12/16 11:52:51','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 4, 'Yes', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (3, to_date('14/07/17 09:01:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 1, 'B', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (4, to_date('14/07/17 09:01:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 2, NULL, to_date('01/07/17 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (5, to_date('14/07/17 09:01:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 5, NULL, to_date('31/07/17 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (6, to_date('14/07/17 11:11:30','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 1, 'A', NULL)
> SELECT * FROM dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
>       select
>             h.record_id
>           , d.trans_dt trans_dt_1
>           , h.trans_dt trans_dt_2
>           , d.field_text
>           , h.field_dt
>           , row_number() over(partition by h.record_id order by h.trans_dt ASC, h.hist_id ASC) rn
>       from history h
>       inner join (
>             select
>                   record_id
>                 , trans_dt
>                 , field_text
>                 , row_number() over(partition by record_id, field_id order by trans_dt ASC) rn
>             from history
>             where field_id = 1
>             and field_text = 'B'
>           ) d on h.record_id = d.record_id and d.rn = 1
>       where h.trans_dt >= d.trans_dt
>       and h.field_id in (2,5)
> ```
>
> ```
> RECORD_ID | TRANS_DT_1 | TRANS_DT_2 | FIELD_TEXT | FIELD_DT  | RN
> --------: | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :-------- | -:
>         1 | 14-JUL-17  | 14-JUL-17  | B          | 01-JUL-17 |  1
>         1 | 14-JUL-17  | 14-JUL-17  | B          | 31-JUL-17 |  2
> ```

> ```
> select
>       record_id
>     , trans_dt_1
>     , trans_dt_2
>     , field_text
>     , field_dt
> FROM (
>       select
>             h.record_id
>           , d.trans_dt trans_dt_1
>           , h.trans_dt trans_dt_2
>           , d.field_text
>           , h.field_dt
>           , row_number() over(partition by h.record_id order by h.trans_dt ASC, h.hist_id ASC) rn
>       from history h
>       inner join (
>             select
>                   record_id
>                 , trans_dt
>                 , field_text
>                 , row_number() over(partition by record_id, field_id order by trans_dt ASC) rn
>             from history
>             where field_id = 1
>             and field_text = 'B'
>           ) d on h.record_id = d.record_id and d.rn = 1
>       where h.trans_dt >= d.trans_dt
>       and h.field_id in (2,5)
>     ) d2
> where d2.rn = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> RECORD_ID | TRANS_DT_1 | TRANS_DT_2 | FIELD_TEXT | FIELD_DT 
> --------: | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------
>         1 | 14-JUL-17  | 14-JUL-17  | B          | 01-JUL-17
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ded3b553a73a335c0416786b8c6bf33d)*

Please note SQLFiddle ceased working (again) so I swapped to dbfiddle instead.

Comment: Great approach, but let me add one more row to the historic data to make it clearer...

Comment: you can do that at sqlfiddle and test it there link provided above but here again http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9856c/9

Comment: there are changes for using hist_id as timebreaker in ordering and using both fields 2 and 5

Comment: Field 5 does not come into this at all. It's a separate field.

Comment: my mistake, just use `and h.field_id = 2` instead of `and h.field_id in (2,5)` which I used above, doesn't change the displayed final result. Have you tried it on real data yet?

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses the revised sample data and sets the date relationship used between the 2 subqueries as **h.trans_dt <= d.trans_dt** (field 1 change date <= field 2 change date). This allows the sample data to meet the expected result (as stated in a comment under the question).

> ```
> CREATE TABLE HISTORY
>     ("HIST_ID" int, "TRANS_DT" date, "RECORD_ID" int, "FIELD_ID" int, "FIELD_TEXT" varchar2(4), "FIELD_DT" date);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (1, to_date('28/11/16 11:37:56','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 3, 'N/A', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (2, to_date('09/12/16 11:52:51','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 4, 'Yes', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (3, to_date('14/07/17 09:01:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 1, 'B', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (4, to_date('14/07/17 09:01:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 2, NULL, to_date('01/07/17 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (5, to_date('14/07/17 09:01:58','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 5, NULL, to_date('31/07/17 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (6, to_date('14/07/17 11:11:30','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1, 1, 'A', NULL)
>     INTO HISTORY ("HIST_ID", "TRANS_DT", "RECORD_ID", "FIELD_ID", "FIELD_TEXT", "FIELD_DT")
>          VALUES (7, to_date('14/07/17 11:11:30','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 1,1, 'A', NULL)
> SELECT * FROM dual;
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select
>       record_id
>     , trans_dt_1
>     , trans_dt_2
>     , field_text
>     , field_dt
> FROM (
>       select
>             h.record_id
>           , d.trans_dt trans_dt_1
>           , h.trans_dt trans_dt_2
>           , d.field_text
>           , h.field_dt
>           , row_number() over(partition by h.record_id order by h.trans_dt ASC, h.hist_id ASC) rn
>       from history h
>       inner join (
>             select
>                   record_id
>                 , trans_dt
>                 , field_text
>                 , row_number() over(partition by record_id, field_id order by trans_dt ASC) rn
>             from history
>             where field_id = 1
>             and field_text = 'A'
>           ) d on h.record_id = d.record_id and d.rn = 1
>       where h.trans_dt <= d.trans_dt
>       and h.field_id  = 2
>     ) d2
> where d2.rn = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> RECORD_ID | TRANS_DT_1 | TRANS_DT_2 | FIELD_TEXT | FIELD_DT 
> --------: | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------
>         1 | 14-JUL-17  | 14-JUL-17  | A          | 01-JUL-17
> ```

The approach uses ROW_NUMBER() because CCL documentation ([here](https://wiki.ucern.com/display/public/1101discernHP/ROW_NUMBER+using+Discern+Explorer)) indicates it is supported and this function, when combined with OVER() is helpful when looking for logic such as "first" or "earliest" (conversely also useful for "last" or "latest") by partitioning and ordering the data to suit.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d2f8e23657b08212f520aa3ce8594d72)*